# TCP parameter tuning on a per connection basis

Tags: linux, performance, networking, tcp

I have listener program on a Linux server with high capacity/speed internet connection which accepts and insert into an SQL Database data uploaded from remote monitoring stations through  GPRS/GSM.

The problem is due to inherent slow high latency nature of these connections many connections are timed out and incompletely inserted into the SQL database.

I cannot tune  Server TCP parameters so these connections can be made to  work properly as other server activities would be affected.

Is there any way I can tune the Network stack on Linux so that high/low latency connections work equally well?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in general make sure you have completed a transaction on a tcp connection that can fail.  The only way to implement such a protocol in a tcp connection is to add a simple command to `commit` (an acknowledged command) and put it **at the end** of every such batch of commands (these can be buffered in groups by tcp).  The command must be a two handshake command (`commit -> ack`) and you have to commit all the transaction on receiving the `command` and rollback if timeout before a `commit` message is received.  The mobile device has to consider commited on receiving the `ack` message (well, you don't need to number the transactions, as TCP makes sure of the arrival order and the sequence of packets) and consider commited all the transactions for which it has received the `ack` message.  Take into account that tcp does the timeout and resending, so you only have to use one send per message and never resend an already sent message.  If you timeout, just throw the connection down and reopen it, considering the last transaction aborted.

Numbering of transactions would be fine to account for the loss of the last `ack` from the server.  If the first transaction id on the next connection is the same as the last of the last connection, you can assume a client has lost his last timeout and is repeating the last transaction again.  In that case, you have to answer with an `ack` to it, and ignore all the commands issued by the client (as they have been already executed by the server.)

This is all necessary to be right at both places (server and client) and don't try to save something or you'll lose data.

A final note is that you don't have something like a timeout for a tcp connection, you have to implement it yourshelf inside the protocol.  A tcp connection can be in the READY state for weeks or even years without exchanging a single packet, just because both parties haven't anything to say to each other.  There's a **KEEP_ALIVE** option for this, but you can only activate it, you have no way to fix the timeout delay for it to fail.

A good example of all this protocols to detect failures is the X protocol.  This is a transaction based protocol, where there are commands issued by the client (there are both styles, commands with a response and commands that do not request such a response) and there are also asynchronous events (signals that come from the server to the client without an acknowledge or a command requesting them)

In this protocol, you have a so called `SYNC` command/service that allows the client to get **in synch** with the server (you use it when you want to assure the server has processed all commands up to now).  Also, the server always send responses/events with the *implicit* request id (incremented for each client command) of the *last executed client request*, so this saves a lot of `SYNC` commands (and roundtrip delays) to the client.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to say that I don't know of a way of tuning the parameters of individual TCP connections (if anyone knows of a way, please share!). You can set socket options for individual connections, but the stack settings I know of are global, set in the kernel.

Second, I don't think that server tuning would even help if the clients are the ones timing out (which I assume is the case, since that wasn't clear). Say you tune the server; you increase the timeout values and add frequent keepalives. What good will it do if the clients are expecting a response from the server within a given time frame? That's a limitation imposed by the client at the application level (unless the TCP connection itself times out, which is unlikely since they are pretty robust and long-lasting by default).